# A deployed Heroku app works online only on the PC I deployed it from

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, heroku

I finished my MERN stack app and deployed it to Heroku. Opened it on Heroku and it worked. Funny thing is, it doesn't work on any other machine other than the one I deployed it from.
When opened on any other machine, it just goes to blank white screen with the following error in console:

```
redux.js:575 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined
    at redux.js:575
    at u (redux.js:79)
    at Module.102 (store.js:9)
    at f ((index):1)
    at Object.57 (spinner.gif:1)
    at f ((index):1)
    at a ((index):1)
    at Array.e [as push] ((index):1)
    at main.4febefcb.chunk.js:1
```

I am trying to figure out what are the possible causes of this behavior.

I've already tried creating a new Heroku app and re-deploying it, restarting dynos and checking my server.js config for ports.

```
//static assets for production
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  //set a static folder
  app.use(express.static("client/build"));
  app.get("*", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "client", "build", "index.html"));
  });
}

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server is being ran on port ${PORT}`));
```

Where should I be looking to locate the issue?

Comment: Could you please post the deployment URL so others can check?

Comment: Also, what does "doesn't work on any other machine" mean? HTTP 404? 500? 200 but a blank screen? Do you get anything in your console? Server side logs? We can't troubleshoot if you don't give us any information. See [ask].

Comment: Added all the info I missed out on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After plenty of debugging, I have isolated the issue to Redux dev tools. The app worked with any browser that had Redux dev tools installed.

I figured out it had something to do with *store.js* file and examined my createStore:

```
 const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  initialState,
  compose(
    applyMiddleware(...middleware),
    window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
  )
);
```

After removing the following line from compose

> window.**REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION** &&
>   window.**REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION**()

I pushed it to Heroku and the problem was solved.

Comment: you need to maintain development and production environments, and conditionally add or remove devtools in each environment respecctively.